# How to handle PopUpWindow with Selenium

Tags: java, javascript, firefox, selenium

I've tried to handle a specific `PopUp / new Window` in Java with `SeleniumServer` but it just doesn't work.
I've done:

```
selenium.click("css=a[title=\"Some irrelevant title\"] > div.text");
Thread.sleep(5000);
    for (String s : selenium.getAllWindowNames()) {
    if (s.contains("_blank")) {
    selenium.selectWindow("name=" + s);
    selenium.windowMaximize();

    }
}
```

But it doesn't recognize the new window. If I use `getAllWindowIDs`or names or titles, it just returns one, the primary window.

If I use `selenium.waitForPopUp("foobar", "9999")` it fails after the timeout, that is why I use a regular `Thread.sleep()`.

What else can I do?

Comment: Just a blind shot: What about `selenium.selectPopup()` without specifying any attribute? It magically helped me once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can help:

```
selenium.RunScript("selenium.browserbot.findElement('css=a[title='Some irrelevant title']').target='my_window'");
selenium.RunScript("window.open('', 'my_window')");
selenium.click("css=a[title='Some irrelevant title']");
selenium.selectWindow("my_window");
selenium.waitForElementPresent("element_locator_at_popup")
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but it doesn't work.. 

It opens a new empty Window and clicks the link but the popup opens in a third window with still no ID...
The clicked-link looks like this:
<a href="/some/path/url" target="_blank" title="Sorry but irrelevant">

Comment: @Matthias, instead of `css=a[title=Some irrelevant title]>div.text` insert `css=a[title=Sorry but irrelevant]`. Edited my initial answer

Comment: I fixed it by using the direct link instead of browsing there so I didn't test your last change. But thanks anyways for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

first do it manualy, click the button after popup came just record something in that pop-up using selenium ide ..if u get window id r title anything else then use that "id" in "waitforpopup" command.

Comment: I did record some actions like isTextPresent in the new Window but the problem is that selenium doesn't recognice the new one and tries to find the text in the old windows.

The new window has no ID, name or title nor it exists for the server..

Comment: first check surely weather it is a pop-up or alert..if alert means jus check weather it is a javascript alert r browser confirm box?

Comment: Its a PopUp, a new browser window and not an alert or confirm box.